# iPhone problem with loading view with button

Tags: iphone

In one of my classes I have a button that when pressed loads another view controller and view. This is what I use:

```
FormController *formController1=[[FormController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:formController1 animated:YES];
```

The problem is that it loads the full view, but not the navigation bar that comes with all the other views. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't be using a modal view controller. If you want the view to appear as part of the navigation stack, you need to load push the view controller onto the navigation view's stack.

If you want the new modal view controller to be a navigation view controller, then make `formController` the root view controller of a UINavigationController, and present the navigation controller as the modal view controller.

Comment: Sorted friend the code is                                   ConfirmController *conf=[[ConfirmController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:conf animated:YES ];

Comment: If you wanted to display your view over the another view you can actually use awakeFromNib(which actually gives you the view) which you need to implement it in your ConfirmController class. you do not use the initWithFrame. but as i can see by naming your class name ConfirmController, is this class to just show the confirmation message or it does some fancy stuff. If it is so then you could have useda simple UIView/UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [`UIViewController` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first:

> On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of *modalViewController* is
>   always presented full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the
>   value in the
>   [`modalPresentationStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle)
>   property.
>
> `presentModalViewController:animated:` sets the
>   [`modalViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalViewController)
>   property to the specified view controller, resizes its view and
>   attaches it to the view hierarchy.

Do you have nib file for your `FormController`? If so, you can set the prompt to Navigation Bar there.

If you wanted to display your view over another view you can use `awakeFromNib` (which actually gives you the view), which must be implemented in your `ConfirmController` class. You do not use `initWithFrame`, but as I can see by your class name `ConfirmController`, is this class just to show a confirmation message or does it do something fancy? If so, then you could have used a simple `UIView`/`UIAlertView`.